# Display a "Back" button, only if there is a back (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Right now I'm using `<a class="bottomNav" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" href="#">Back</a><br />`
But then it will always be displayed, even when the "back" button won't lead anywhere.
How can I check if there is a "back" before displaying the button?

I wanted to check the action and controller, for example: `if(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue != "Home")`
But it is not accurate because I still need the "back" sometimes

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
@if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    <a class="bottomNav" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" href="#">Back</a><br />
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a small question.. I used "if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)" without the @.. what does "@" before the if statement means?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you're using ASP.NET MVC 2... I wrote this in Razor syntax which is used in ASP.NET MVC 3... @ sign is just alternative of <% sign in ASP. NET MVC 2... So you have no need in @ sign :)

Comment: Why do not use Request.UrlReferrer in herf link instead javascript method? Is it cause some problems?

Answer (score 0):

You could check `document.referrer`. If this property is set then you can show the link